# How to output a JSONObject clearly

Tags: java, json

As title, I want to output a JSONObject like this
https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552
Every line is separately.
Is there a easy way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [JSONObject.toString(indent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28int%29)?